# vscode debug webpack + typescript + references

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, webpack

I have TS project which is referencing another TS project

VS Code breakpoints work find in the parent project, but I want to be able to step into the referenced project and step through that code. Is that possible?

```
git clone https://github.com/CodeOfLight/debug-jest-lib.git
git clone https://github.com/CodeOfLight/debug-jest-ref.git
cd debug-jest-lib
npm install
cd ..
cd debug-jest-ref
npm install
#Launch VS Code
code .
# Inser a breakpoint in src/index.ts
# press F5 to begin debug
```

Index.ts looks as follows:

```
import {math} from '@mathlib'

let result = math.add(1,1);
let message: string = 'Adding 1 and 1 produces: ';
console.log(message +result);
```

I want to be able to step into the math.add(1,1) function.

Note that @mathlib is setup as an alias in the webpack file so that webpack knows not to look for it as a npm package and instead expects it on disk.